# JSP difference between not empty vs != null?

Tags: jsp

For JSP's not empty some_var vs some_var != null, what is the difference?

Which one should I use to determine if a variable is undefined/unset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not empty will also let you catch empty strings "" in addition to explicit nulls. You will get an error if a property is undefined. You can trap for that like so:

```
<c:catch var="exception">${myObject.myAttribute}</c:catch>
```

I can't find the authoritative docs from Oracle.

Comment: Does it catch if a variable is not defined? Also can you link me to a documentation because apparently I am terrible at google. I'm asking because I'm seeing some weird behavior when I use not empty to check if a variable is defined.